# how to delete selected row from database in GridControl

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I am new on DevExpress. I retrieve data from database to gridview and can display them so far. However, I have a button which makes several modifications when user clicks on it.

I can remove the selected row from gridview.
So my obvious question is how can I delete selected rows from database in gridview.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    Dim cevap As DialogResult = DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Dikkat!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If cevap = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then Exit Sub

    Dim command As New SqlCommand()
    command.Connection = spcc.SqlCon

    'command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM EBARPARAMETER WHERE ID = '" & GridView1.what? & "' "



    Dim read As SqlDataReader
    read = command.ExecuteReader()
    GridView1.DeleteRow(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Posting Data to a Connected Database](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1082) help-article:
The [GridView.DeleteRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_DeleteRowtopic) method removes a row from a grid's View and also deletes the object which represents this row in the GridControl's data source, but not from a database. To accomplish your task, **you need to post changes to the database manually**, for example using corresponding the methods of a Data Adapter object or EF-context.

> GridView1.what?

To get row objects that correspond to specific row handles, use the [ColumnView.GetRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic) or [ColumnView.GetDataRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataRowtopic) method. 
In specific cases, you may need to obtain indexes of rows in the bound data source that correspond to specific row handles in Views. To do this, use the [ColumnView.GetDataSourceRowIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetDataSourceRowIndextopic.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks DmirtyG. I could make it by using GridView.FocusedValue property.